# How to make a pixel translucent?

Tags: java

I want to darken part of the window. At first I thought of putting a translucent png image in that section for this. But I guess it would be primitive to use a picture for this work and my schedule would take up more space in vain?
How can I do this?
Another way that comes to my mind:

```
g2d.drawImage(darkenImage, 0, 0, this);
// or
Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 100);
```

I don't know how I can paint the pixels I want with this color.
Note: I'm doing all my drawings on a JPanel.

Comment: This question requires more clarity. In terms of available platforms, Java is an incredibly distributed language, so "making a pixel translucent" is different for a whole host of platforms and / or frameworks. Please provide more detail on your problem

Comment: @jonny I'm not sure I fully understand what you say, but I tried to make it clearer

Comment: You could use `fillRect()` to draw a black, partially transparent rectangle over your ContentPane. Whether you achieve the desired result depends heavily on whether the elements to be darkened are really drawn first. If you can make sure of that, it should work.

Comment: Perhaps [javax.swing.JLayer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLayer.html) is appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. Here is a possible solution:

```
public class Darken {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            protected void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
                super.paintChildren(g);
                g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 96));
                g.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
            }
        };
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        panel.add(new JButton("Ok"));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("Darken Test");
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes fillRect is really short and useful. Thanks for answer. I want to ask one more thing. I'm trying to code a little game and I'm encoding everything into a JPanel. So actually I do not take advantage of Swing's facilities and I am writing everything in awt logic. Do you think this is ridiculous? Swing is intimidating to me, do you think I should learn?

Comment: This is definitely not ridiculous. You don't need Swing to develop a game. But it is definitely not a disadvantage to deal with it.

Comment: So you mean using "Swing" has its advantages, but it's not necessary, right?

Comment: As long as you don't need any text entry fields, combo boxes, tables, buttons, etc., you can do without Swing. Otherwise you will need Swing or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

There's two possibilities:

1. Create a translucent, undecorated window. All painting actions will make is seem "the background" changes
2. Take a screenshot, display that on a fullscreen-window, do the manipulations on that

To have translucent colors, use the CTOR `new Color(r,g,b,a)` where rgba ar either int values from 0-255 or float values from 0-1. The a is the transparency.

**Update to edited question:**

There's the GlassPane in every swing window (JFrame, JDialog, JWindow etc). On that GlassPane you can do the additional drawings without influencing the ContentPane's conents. Simply get the glasspane: `window.getGlassPane();` or create a new JComponent (JPanel etc) if the default does not suffice: `JPanel myGlass = new JPanel(); window.setGlassPane(myGlass);`. GlassPanes are used for informative drawing, for example arrows, cursor highlighters and other things, that might be inconvenient to do on the ContentPane.

The GlassPanel works well together with semi-transparent colors, as stated above.

Comment: oh yes actually this is a very good information but what I mean is to darken part of my window, not the screen.

Comment: Ah yes. There's the GlassPane in every swing window (JFrame, JDialog, JWindow etc). On that GlassPane you can do the additional drawings without influencing the ContentPane's conents. Simply get the glasspane: `window.getGlassPane();` or create a new JComponent (JPanel etc) if the default does not suffice: `JPanel myGlass = new JPanel(); window.setGlassPane(myGlass);`. GlassPanes are used for informative drawing, for example arrows, cursor highlighters and other things, that might be inconvenient to do on the ContentPane.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing. I'm trying to code a little game and I'm encoding everything into a JPanel. So actually I do not take advantage of Swing's facilities and I am writing everything in awt logic. Do you think this is ridiculous? Swing is intimidating to me, do you think I should learn?

Comment: Well... a JPanel actually IS Swing. (Panel would be AWT) Mixing both AWT and Swing... well... it works. But why downgrade? I personally like Swing the most of all UI frameworks. Coming from AWT, Swing is no big step. So why be afraid?

Comment: The paint logic was a bit difficult for me, who was used to AWT. Okay, I'll try the swing. Is there a quality resource you can recommend?

Comment: https://google.com